# Bootstrap modal id use in vue.js method for show and hide modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Here is my method for showing bootstrap modal and #BlogModal is modal id.

```
        editBlog(blog){
            this.editMode = true;
            this.BlogForm.fill(blog);
            $('#BlogModal').modal('show');
        },
```

But when this code executes then showing me this error.

[image]

How can I solve it? Please help me...

Comment: How did you setup your project? please share your package.json and main.js

Comment: do you have the jquery lib at any point included?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/hanif57b/vue_crud/-/blob/master/package.json

Comment: https://gitlab.com/hanif57b/vue_crud/-/blob/master/src/main.js

Comment: yes. jQuery is here included in index.html

Comment: Jquery seems to be undefined as error `'$' is not defined` said it. Try typing some Jquery script in your browser console to be sure that it is correctly imported. If it is, perhaps it is not imported before your method is triggered. **Jquery must be imported before bootstrap.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **document.getElementById('BlogModal')** or you can give a ref to your modal as below.

```
<input ref="input" />
```

Access to DOM from script tags:
this.$refs.input